# How to use ui-routing with ionic slide box?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

The ionic slide box requires routing with the script tag like these:
    http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/Kbpyg/

Here, it is accomplished by using the `<script>` tags and giving `id` attribute as `something.html` in a single page. I am looking for a slider implementation where I can make use of the `$stateProvider` of ionic framework (`ng-route` doesn't work here), and make different html templates for each page.

Comment: You want the state to change each time you slide?

Comment: Yes. And by that load a different html page altogether just like in ui-routing

Comment: @bhargav Is there any solution to that?

Comment: I think you will have to use the "$stateProvider" provided by ionic. The default angular routing ".when()" doesn't work here (it used to in cordova)

Comment: Will you use tabs? Or just a swipe from page to page?

Comment: @andy I initially wanted tabs. But I didn't find any solutions. So I settled for swipe from page to page.

Answer (score 0):

Pass an index as a stateparameter to your state, ensure you have a delegate-handle on your slider, and you can slide to a particular index in your controller as follows:

example controller:

```
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams, $slideBoxDelegate){
            var mySlider = angular.getElementById(document.getElementById('mySliderContainer'));
            var handle = mySlider.querySelector('.slider').getAttribute('delegate-handle');
            var ionicSlideBoxDelegate = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate;

            $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(){
                    var index = $stateParams.index;
                    ionicSlideBoxDelegate = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle(handle);
                    ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
            });
   });
```

You can move through slides using the ionicSlideBoxDelegate. 
Above code should work, however I haven't tested it.